# Sizing and alignment of MenuItem and icon graphic JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a right click menu here and as you can see it shows up nicely:

[image]

When I try to add a right click menu to another table, it shows up like this:

[image]

Can I re-align the graphic or can I force the `MenuItems` to be the right size?

Here is the code (I add it to both tables the same way):

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(TableCommons.getAttendanceMenuItem(30),
                                          TableCommons.getAttendanceMenuItem(10),
                                          TableCommons.getAttendanceMenuItem(5));

this.table.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

---

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIconView;

static MenuItem getAttendanceMenuItem(int number)
{
    MenuItem attendanceMenuItem = new MenuItem(number + " day Attendance");

    MaterialDesignIconView materialDesignIconView = new MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.FILE_WORD_BOX);

    materialDesignIconView.setSize("1em");
    materialDesignIconView.setFill(Main.OFFICE_WORD_BLUE_COLOUR);
    attendanceMenuItem.setGraphic(materialDesignIconView);    

    return attendanceMenuItem;    

}
```

Comment: You know the drill ;) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try but I can't figure out why the `MenuItems` actually become taller in some `TableViews` and not others. Not sure how I can replicate it.

Comment: I took the glyph out and it seems the height goes back to normal. So the problem lies with the glyph being set as the graphic....

Comment: try to look with scenicview at your 2nd menu to see who is responsible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into this: it's due to padding which is set in the default JavaFX stylesheet, `modena.css`. The OP doesn't make their exact scenario clear, but I was running into the issue when trying to add a context menu to items in a dialog; the menu item graphics always had additional padding.

I'm not a CSS expert, but I think the offending lines of code from `modena.css` are the following:

```
.dialog-pane:no-header .graphic-container {
    -fx-padding: 0.833em 0 0 0.833em; /* 10px 0px 0px 10px */
}
```

I was able to fix it by adding the following to my own stylesheet, to override the default:

```
.menu-item > .graphic-container {
    -fx-padding: 0em 0.333em 0em 0em;
}
```

Comment: Interesting fix. I wonder what made it work some of the time for me and not the rest of the time.